# How to get data from 2 different models in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new at this, trying to learn new django and python tricks

I am making a project where authors can upload a design, the name of this app is "score" where there model.py as shown below:

score app model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to='')
```

I also have another app which is called "core" where there is an Item model. I want to be able manually from the admin to chose the name of the author and in the next design choice i only get his uploaded designs.

I know I have to make a tuple of choice

here is the core app model.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField()
    design= models.ImageField()
```

Comment: Are you talking about the ORM query to join both tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Foreign keys to maintain relationship between items and users. So in class Item it will be:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and for getting all the designs or items of an author you can use:

```
user.design_set.all()
```

or

```
Design.objects.filter(author.id=request.user.id)
```

or for your Foreign key you can set a related_name such as items so your code will be: 
`author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')`

and you can retrieve all items for an author by:

`user.items.all()` in python and `user.items.all` in Django template.

For additional reference about relationships and foreign key please visit:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is really helpful but regarding design i want it also to be a drop down list "ForeignKey" so that when I choose an author only his designs show in the drop down. I wrote this code but getting an error  `design = models.ForeignKey(Design.objects.filter(author.id=request.user.id), , on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: `Design.objects.filter(author.id=request.user.id)`  with give you all the objects assigned to the user you do not need to do that Django automatically assigns Foreign keys to objects you can retrieve the objects of the user by the code above.